# How to output the Panel node's template name in the Body class list

Tags: panels, theming

Is there a way to access a Panel's template name to output in the body of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I'm using in my Zen subtheme's template.php

```
// Add the panel's template name to the page's body classes
if($panel_page = page_manager_get_current_page()) {
  $display = panels_get_current_page_display();
  $layout = $display->layout;
  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'panel-layout-' . $layout;
}
```

Hope that helps!